# Jar file does not work after renaming classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

Typing this from my phone as I got off my computer and am about to go to sleep so please ignore typos. Anyway I have a project I was working on that makes a jar file that allows me to config some things and then build a new jar file with what I set. I decided I did not like the class names for the builder and the output file, so I changed them (just changed com.john to com.epix type of thing) and updated all required things. The builder can be built and ran perfectly fine, and the output file can be built from eclipse and ran perfectly fine, however now when I try to build the file using the builder it tells me "main class not found" when I try to run the file. The thing that is really bugging me is if I pack the jar file my self (putting the nessesary files into a zip then renaming it to a jar) it works, which is where I get confused as its packing the same exact files. I assume there to be something wrong in the builder itself but the only thing that changed code-wise were just some imports. Has anyone else encountered this type of problem or know a fix? And yes I set the main class in the manifest and class path. Can't paste any code right now, as previously stated am on phone. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I have been scratching my head for the past 4 hours.

Comment: Have you tried defining a builder for your project and specifying the source directory? You also might want to consider linking to a screenshot of the issue so that we can see the error that you're talking about in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you updated manifest file??

Comment: The problem is eclipse gives me no errors, I only get an error when I build the jar using the builder, the files are in the jar and if I pack it myself it works, was working perfectly before the rename and now its just not.

Comment: Have you looked for and are you seeing the red-bang ( ! ) next to any projects?

Comment: No, as I said no errors or warnings from eclipse :(